How to organise data with missing values to achieve minimum number of tables
The task is to create sub-tables from an original table (like below) that contain the missing data columns (missing data is highlighted in red). The important part of this task is to make the smallest number of output tables based on the combinations of missing data points across different columns for different rows. (Specifically to always reach this optimal solution of the minimum number of output tables.)
Input Table:



Name
Code
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N




Example1
Example1





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example2
Example2





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example3
Example3





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example4
Example4





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example5
Example5





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example6
Example6





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example7
Example7





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example8
Example8
1
1
1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1
1
1
1


Example9
Example9
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1



Example10
Example10
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1



Example11
Example11
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1



Example12
Example12





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example13
Example13





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example14
Example14





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example15
Example15
1
1
1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1
1
1
1


Example16
Example16





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example17
Example17





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example18
Example18





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1


Example19
Example19
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1
1


Example20
Example20
1
1
1
1
1
1

1

1
1
1
1
1


Example21
Example21
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1



Example22
Example22
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1



Example23
Example23





1
1
1
1

1
1
1
1



Input Table
In the above example the optimal output will create 4 tables such as the ones that are shown below. These tables include common columns that are missing across different examples.
Table 1



Name
Code
A
B
C
D
E
J




Example1
Example1








Example2
Example2








Example3
Example3








Example4
Example4








Example5
Example5








Example6
Example6








Example7
Example7








Example12
Example12








Example13
Example13








Example14
Example14








Example16
Example16








Example17
Example17








Example18
Example18








Example23
Example23









Table 2



Name
Code
G




Example8
Example8



Example15
Example15



Example20
Example20




Table 3



Name
Code
N




Example9
Example9



Example10
Example10



Example11
Example11



Example21
Example21



Example22
Example22




Table 4



Name
Code
I




Example19
Example19



Example20
Example20




Output Tables
This is the code that works to output these tables. An interesting element which this code does not cover and why it can be improved is that the Example20 row is correctly split across Table2 and Table4 as they had been created previously (and IsSubset returned True). However, had Example20 appeared earlier in the data set, a table would have been created for it with the two columns that it has missing ("G" and "I") and then we would have ended up with 5 output tables as we would also have had tables that covered I and G individually which is not the optimal solution. We are looking for an optimised code that finds optimal solution consistently regardless of the order of the rows.
Sub GroupDataOptimised()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim outputRow As Long
    Dim missingKey As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim missingDict As Object
    Dim existingKeys As Variant
    Dim headers() As String
    Dim foundSubset As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    ' Define input sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Missing Data")
    
    ' Create a new workbook for output
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    
    ' Initialise dictionaries to keep track of missing data
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set missingDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Find the last row and column in the input data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Loop through each row to identify missing data patterns
    For currentRow = 2 To lastRow
        missingKey = ""
        
        ' Construct a key that represents missing columns
        For col = 3 To lastCol ' Start from 3 to skip "Name" and "Code"
            If ws.Cells(currentRow, col).Value = "" Then
                missingKey = missingKey & ws.Cells(1, col).Value & "|"
            End If
        Next col
        
        ' If there is missing data
        If missingKey <> "" Then
            foundSubset = False
            existingKeys = dict.Keys
            
            ' Check all existing patterns for subset matches
            For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
                Dim existingKey As String
                existingKey = existingKeys(i)
                
                ' Check if current missingKey is a subset of existingKey or vice versa
                If IsSubset(existingKey, missingKey) Then
                    foundSubset = True
                    ' Output the row to the existing subset sheet
                    Set wsOutput = missingDict(existingKey)
                    outputRow = wsOutput.Cells(wsOutput.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    
                    wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 1).Value = ws.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value ' Name
                    wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value ' Code
                    
                    ' Fill in the missing columns as blanks
                    headers = Split(existingKey, "|")
                    For j = 0 To UBound(headers) - 1
                        If headers(j) <> "" Then
                            For col = 3 To lastCol
                                If wsOutput.Cells(1, col).Value = headers(j) Then
                                    wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, col).Value = "" ' Missing column data
                                End If
                            Next col
                        End If
                    Next j
                End If
            Next i
            
            ' If no matching subset found, create a new table for this missing data pattern
            If Not foundSubset Then
                dict.Add missingKey, dict.Count + 1
                
                ' Create a new worksheet for each unique pattern of missing data
                Set wsOutput = wbNew.Sheets.Add(After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count))
                wsOutput.Name = "Missing_" & dict.Count
                
                ' Add headers to the new sheet
                wsOutput.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
                wsOutput.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Code"
                
                ' Add the column names that are missing
                headers = Split(missingKey, "|")
                For col = 0 To UBound(headers) - 1
                    If headers(col) <> "" Then
                        wsOutput.Cells(1, col + 3).Value = headers(col)
                    End If
                Next col
                
                ' Initialize missing data dictionary
                missingDict.Add missingKey, wsOutput
                
                ' Output the current row to the new sheet
                outputRow = 2
                wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 1).Value = ws.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value ' Name
                wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value ' Code
                
                ' Fill in the missing columns as blanks
                For j = 0 To UBound(headers) - 1
                    If headers(j) <> "" Then
                        wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, j + 3).Value = "" ' Missing column data
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        End If
    Next currentRow
    
    ' Adjust column widths for better readability in each output sheet
    For Each wsOutput In wbNew.Sheets
        wsOutput.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next wsOutput
    
    MsgBox "Missing data grouped by missing columns in a new workbook!", vbInformation
End Sub

' Function to check if one key is a subset of another
' key1: A string representing a set of missing column names separated by "|"
' key2: Another string representing a different set of missing column names separated by "|"
' Returns: True if key1 is a subset of key2, False otherwise
Function IsSubset(key1 As String, key2 As String) As Boolean
    ' Declare arrays to hold the column names extracted from key1 and key2
    Dim arr1() As String, arr2() As String
    ' Loop variables
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    ' Flag to indicate if a match is found
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    ' Split the keys into arrays of column names using the "|" delimiter
    arr1 = Split(key1, "|") ' Array of missing column names from key1
    arr2 = Split(key2, "|") ' Array of missing column names from key2
    
    ' If key1 has more elements than key2, it cannot be a subset
    If UBound(arr1) > UBound(arr2) Then
        ' key1 should be smaller or equal in length to key2 to be a subset
        IsSubset = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each element in arr1 (representing key1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr1) - 1
        ' Skip empty elements caused by trailing or leading delimiters
        If arr1(i) <> "" Then
            found = False ' Reset the found flag for each element in arr1
            ' Loop through each element in arr2 (representing key2)
            For j = 0 To UBound(arr2) - 1
                ' If the current element in arr1 matches an element in arr2
                If arr1(i) = arr2(j) Then
                    found = True ' Set the found flag to True
                    Exit For ' No need to continue searching in arr2 for this element
                End If
            Next j
            ' If no match is found in arr2 for the current element in arr1
            If Not found Then
                IsSubset = False ' key1 is not a subset of key2
                Exit Function ' Exit the function early
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' If all elements in arr1 are found in arr2, key1 is a subset of key2
    IsSubset = True
End Function


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

I do not have the reputation to comment, but on @TinMan's answer I have tried running an example through the model and achieved a sub-optimal outcome.
Example Data



Name
Code
A
B
C




Example1
Example1


1


Example2
Example2





Example3
Example3
1





When running this through the model it generated 3 tables as below:
Table 1



Name
Code
A




Example1
Example1



Example2
Example2




Table 2



Name
Code
B




Example1
Example1



Example2
Example2



Example3
Example3




Table 3



Name
Code
C




Example2
Example2



Example3
Example3




However, using an approach based on my initial comment (below) where you start with the smallest count of missing columns you could achieve this outcome:
Table 1



Name
Code
A
B




Example1
Example1




Example2
Example2





Table 2



Name
Code
B
C




Example2
Example2




Example3
Example3





Similarly to what @Greedo suggested to use some sort of graph searching algorithm on this problem - it provides an interesting way to view this example. The image below shows the two rectangles (squares) that can be drawn around the missing values.

Just looking at this problem logically, you could take the total set of missing column combinations and then order them based on number of missing columns. Then, when creating the tables, create them starting with the smallest number of missing columns first and then check the subset condition for each subsequent table. This way you would never create a table that could potentially have been unnecessary (as would have been the case if Example20 had appeared earlier in the dataset, as mentioned). Unfortunately, this would require a better coder than me to implement!

I think having the ranges overlap is probably not what the Original Question was after. It seems to me they have a dataset with blanks and want an algorithm to pull all the blanks out and present them to the user to fill in. Having repetitions would go against this. But maybe that's just my additional constraint.

Paste [D1,H1:J1,C1:C2,B1:B3,H3,A1:A4,I4,G1:G5,J5] = 1 in the Immediate window and press enter.   To create 2 datasets.  The first dataset produces 3 tables working from the row with the most missing data to the least and 6 tables going from the least to the most.   The second table yields 3 tables least to most and 4 most to least.


Blank cells pattern should covers all cols. It is used as the key of Dict object.

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey, sVal As String
    Dim arrData, oWK As Workbook
    Dim oSrcSht As Worksheet, NameCode As String
    Const SHT_NAME = "Missing_"
    Set oSrcSht = Sheets("Sheet2")  ' modify as needed
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = oSrcSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' concat Name and Code
        NameCode = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2)
        sKey = ""
        ' locate blank cell
        For j = 3 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            sVal = arrData(i, j)
            If Len(sVal) = 0 Then ' cocate col header
                sKey = sKey & "|" & arrData(1, j)
            End If
        Next
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            sKey = Mid(sKey, 2) ' remove leading delimeter
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then ' add to Dict
                objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & NameCode
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = NameCode
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    i = 0
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, aTxt, aRes(), aName, iR As Long
    If objDic.Count > 0 Then
        Set oWK = Workbooks.Add
        For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
            i = i + 1
            ' Create or get new sheet
            If i = 1 Then
                Set oSht = Sheets(1)
            Else
                Set oSht = oWK.Sheets.Add(, oWK.Sheets(oWK.Sheets.Count))
            End If
            With oSht
                .Name = SHT_NAME & i
                ' populate header row
                .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Name", "Code")
                aTxt = Split(sKey, "|")
                For j = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
                    .Cells(1, j + 3).Value = aTxt(j)
                Next
                ' populdate Name and Code cols
                aTxt = Split(objDic(sKey), ",")
                ReDim aRes(UBound(aTxt), 1)
                iR = 0
                For j = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
                    aName = Split(aTxt(j), "|")
                    aRes(iR, 0) = aName(0)
                    aRes(iR, 1) = aName(1)
                    iR = iR + 1
                Next
                .Range("A2").Resize(iR, 2).Value = aRes
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub



Thanks @taller for the solution, this is a much more elegant way of achieving the same result. However, when running your code the solution is sub-optimal, you create 5 tables where 4 is possible?

May I know what's the logic that Example20 belongs to two output tables? ie. Example19 and 20 don't have same missing cols.

Since the objective is to create the smallest number of tables, it is a better outcome to allocate Example20 to Table 2 and Table 4 (G and I tables) rather than create a new table for it.

Well I've figured out how to solve this graphically.
Take this example:




x1
x2
x3
x4




y1
1

1



y2

1

1


y3
1

1



y4

1

1


y5
1

1




In this pattern the most optimal thing is to move rows and columns to untangle the chess board pattern. First the rows




x1
x2
x3
x4




y1
1

1



y3
1

1



y5
1

1



y2

1

1


y4

1

1



Then the columns



Column1
x1
x3
x2
x4




y1
1
1




y3
1
1




y5
1
1




y2


1
1


y4


1
1



Giving 2 obvious regions of blanks. Now if we imagine the blank representing an edge in a graph between e.g. x2 and y1, x4 and y5 etc, we get the following:

These 2 subgraphs show the 2 blank regions as separate sections. This makes intuitive sense - if two column headings have connection to two row headings, they will be clustered into a group of 4. A subgraph is valid as a subtable if every "x" connects to every "y", since then it will only contain blanks (the connection represents a blank).
Or using the example from the post:

Now it's not true that we'll always get these separate subgraphs - e.g. "I" and "G" look connected, but 2 nodes can only be put in the same table if they share all their connections. So the algorithm for doing this programmatically would be a bit tricky but hopefully that's a start.
If you think of the row headings as the "odd" nodes, and the column headings as "even" nodes, then it should be possible to walk the graph keeping track of whether an odd node is connected to n even nodes which themselves are all connected to another odd node, then those odd nodes can be clustered.
There is more than one way to cluster while making sure every edge (blank) falls in at least one cluster, e.g.


vs

So the algorithm will have to be a bit smart here
